# Issues in combobox selection

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am new to vba excel and i have been successful in putting a conditional combobox which is dependent on a drop down list selection, the problem i am facing is whenever i click on any item in the combobox ,it does not appear in the box after the click.

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem.

thank you

The code i used is :

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
ComboBox1.Clear


If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "PHE" Then
With ComboBox1

For row = 1 To 1300
.AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, 6)
Next row
End With

End If

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "HSS" Then
With ComboBox1
For row = 2 To 56
.AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, 8)
Next row
End With

End If

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "Decanter" Then
With ComboBox1
For row = 3 To 249
.AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, 9)
Next row
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to somehow interpret the value that was selected, perhaps you could just reset the value of the combobox.  This only applies if the value is being selected properly, just not visible in the combobox.

```
ComboBox1.Value = something
```

Also, this could be much cleaner (writing code here, so typos may exist).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

ComboBox1.Clear

Select Case Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value
Case "PHE"
  minrow = 1
  maxrow = 1300
  col = 6
Case "HSS"
  minrow = 2
  maxrow = 56
  col = 8
Case "Decanter"
  minrow = 3
  maxrow = 249
  col = 9
Case Else
  'error handling
End Select

With ComboBox1
  For row = minrow To maxrow
    .AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, col)
  Next row
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a cleaner code but can you tell me how to direct the value of the combobox on which we "click" to the ComboBox1.Value = something

Comment: That is how can we make the combobox item on which we click to appear in the combobox . Please Help